# iphone image picker result url

Tags: iphone, url, uiimagepickercontroller

HI in my app the user can take a picture or select one from the gallery and then it is displayed in a small image view. I need to get the resulting image url to save it in a database and then I will use that url to send the image to the server (that is done this way only when the is no internet connection available). All this works I have this code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

NSURL *url=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
NSLog(@"%@",url);

//(.....)
}
```

When I save the url to database I just pass it as if it was a string parameter and it works and I have looked in the database the url is there in the form:

assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5A900026-5994-4F93-8A49-D2C96BDA2659&ext=JPG

my problem is when I try to use this url either to get image or to get data it gives me error or empty object:

```
NSData *dataForFile =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[url path]];
UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[url path]];
```

url path=asset.JPG/ strange....

I also tried like this:

```
 NSData *dataForFile =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:url];
```

but it also doesn't work. I only need either of them a data object or an image (from image I can get data), how could I do that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use [assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure this is the one you need, since that is an asset URL (you'll need to link the`ALAssetsFramework` to the project target).

You can then get the image data from the `ALAsset`.

**EDIT:** This should work to get the full resolution image from the given url (if the url is still valid):

```
__block UIImage *image=nil;
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset){
  ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
  image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror){
  NSLog(@"Cannot get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
  //
};
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
NSLog(@"%@", image);
```

I used almost similar code in some projects, but I haven't tested this one.

**Edit 2:** Ran a couple of tests today. It seems the blocks are running asynchronously, which means the image will not be available right after calling `[assetslibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];`. Instead, you can use the image from inside the `resultblock`. There's also no more reason to declare `image` as a `block` variable, so the code will become:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset){
  ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
  #warning todo: use image here, or call a method and pass 'image' to it
};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror){
  NSLog(@"Cannot get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
NSURL *url=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
```

Comment: thks it looks kind of complicated. luckily I have found a tutorial: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/

Comment: it's not very complicated, except that it's using blocks. I've updated with some code that I believe will work fine.

Comment: doesn't work for me i put it inside the 
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{} method and I use the url I get from the info dic but image stays null so I guess it doesn't work in iphone 5 or I am missing something